# Eclipse support for custom facelets tags

Tags: java, eclipse, facelets, taglib

I recently started facelets development, and a couple of days ago made my first useful custom tag. Now I would like to have auto-completion support in eclipse, like I have for standard taglibs like h, c and ui.

Is there any easy way (less than 30 min work) to enable tool support for custom tags?

I'm using eclipse 3.4 with jboss tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jboss Tools 3.0M3 or newer.
About it support of custom facelets you can find information here [Jboss Tools Forum](http://www.jboss.org/index.html?module=bb&op=viewtopic&t=154315)

Answer (score 0):

What version of Eclipse are you using?

My current version (Version: 3.4.0, Build id: I20080617-2000, with WTP)has autocompletion for any taglib added as a directive on my JSP page (even if the current JSP file does a `<%@ include file="..." %>` to the actual file with the taglib declarations in it), even the non-standard ones.

For example, Eclipse will autocomplete any `<form:blah>` tags for me if I have the following declaration:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

Comment: guess facelets work a little different, both in the views and in the implementation of custom tags, so I think custom facelets tags aren't automatically supported even if custom jsp tags are. But, again, I'm new with facelets and might be wrong.